# Using jsonp in jquery seems to always fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I get 'error' almost no matter what I'm trying to load in using the dataType 'jsonp' in the ajax method of jquery, however using just 'json' works fine for the same json content. I need to use jsonp because I'm calling an external API to work with.

Js method:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'test3.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'APICALL',
                ID: '59'
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
             console.log('success');
            },
            error: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
             console.log('error: '+textStatus);
             console.log(data);
            },
            complete: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
             console.log('complete');
            }

        });

})
```

test3.json file:

```
{"symbol": "IBM", "price": "91.42"}
```

Comment: can you visit this `test3.json` in your browser? if so, try the fully qualified url.

Comment: you also need dataType: 'jsonp' as well as a callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not JSONP.

You need to write a [JSONP endpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) that honors the `callback` parameter.

Comment: I think I misunderstood how jsonp works. All I'm really trying to do is get a prefabricated json response and use it across domains.

Comment: Correct.  JSONP is not magic; you need to implement it correctly. See Wikipedia.